# Chrome extension disabled every time version is changed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have a Chrome extension which is published in the webstore. Every time I update the version number and publish again, Chrome disables the extension and I have to re-enable it, and approve the permissions again.

The permissions haven't changed, only the version number of the extension (and a minor change to javascript within the extension.)

The relevant part of my manifest has:

```
"version":          "1.2.1",
"manifest_version": 2,

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.website1.com https://subdomain.website1.com https://subdomain.website2.com/ https://www.website3.com/; object-src 'self'",

"permissions":            [
    "cookies",
    "management",
    "tabs",
    "http://*.website1.com/*",
    "https://*.website1.com/*",
    "https://*.website2.com/*",
    "https://*.website4.com/*"
],
```

The other fields I set in the manifest are:

```
"name":
"short_name":
"description":
"icons":
"browser_action":
"commands":
"background":
"externally_connectable":
"content_scripts":
```

Is this a bug in Chrome? Or is there something I'd have to add/remove to not have the extension disabled when the version changes?

Comment: This is a bug with the extension not Chrome.  Contact the author of the extension.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - I'm the author. Any suggestions on where to look, or how to debug/fix?

Comment: Look into where you configure the supported versions of your extension.  You should be using a wild card or the configuration that allows all version above a certain version.

Comment: I've added the "version" and "manifest_version" I'm using above. I don't set the "minimum_chrome_version" - should I? Or is there a different version you mean? (I don't see anything in the developer dashboard, can't think of anywhere else to look.)